# Packaging Android app using Dart content shell

Tags: android, dart, package-development

The only way I aware about it now to package Dart app as Android app, is to get it converted to javascript, and use it in a webview.

My question or thinking today is:
Is there a chance or a way to package the DART application with the 2 files mentioned below in a way similar to Chrome web store packaged app, or as Mozilla Marketplace packaged app to get it run in Android.

the 2 files I'm talking about are:

```
Content_Shell_Developer_Build.apk
```

and

```
Dart_Editor_Mobile_Connection_Service_1.0.apk
```

thanks

Comment: I think you can use Cordova for this - I haven't used it myself yet though. http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html, https://github.com/rikulo/gap

Comment: Thanks, this is also deal with JavaScript, not DART, I'm looking for a way to avoid the dart2js conversion, if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the dart2js conversion. The only ways to run applications built with Dart on Android is transpiling them to JavaScript or run them as a console application without a GUI or with a native extension for Android that makes use of the Android C/C++ API.

Now there is also Sky https://github.com/domokit/sky_engine